# Always Fire Observable Event on Same Value with Knockout.js without ValueHasMutated

Tags: knockout.js, publish-subscribe

Is there a more convenient way to always notify an observable of a change, even if the value is the same without using `valueHasMutated` on every call?

I have a grid of cells that has an inner list of observables of properties.  I am keeping a history of the grid.

I know the grid is updated by using an observable boolean called hasUpdate below.  However, this property below doesn't fire when I call it a second time because of a second change in the grid.

I'd hate to call `valueHasMutated` every time I update the hasUpdate property below.

```
app.viewModel.members.hasUpdate.subscribe(function (update) {
    if (update)
        viewModel.undo.add(viewModel.grid());
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [notify extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#forcing-observables-to-always-notify-subscribers):

```
app.viewModel.members.hasUpdate.extend({
    notify: 'always' 
});
```

This will make sure `hasUpdate`'s subscribers will always be notified, even if the new value did not change.